Error while connecting to ADO project from eclipse
Getting the below error while connecting to Azure Devops from Eclipse in Team Explorer view. While adding server before entering the credentials.
enter image description here
Is it my Azure Devops login is not working or issue with version. We are using Eclipse 2023-09 & Team explorer everywhere 14.137.0.
If we try the same Team explorer version with Eclipse 2023-03, the below error occurs.
enter image description here

There's a 14.139.0 release. Given that it's for connecting to a service, you should really be on the current one if possible.

Based on the statement on the documentation "Share your code in Git using Eclipse",

The Team Explorer Everywhere plug-in works with Eclipse versions 4.2 (Juno) - 4.6 (Neon).


The Eclipse versions you are use:

Eclipse IDE 2023-03: Eclipse 4.27.0
Eclipse IDE 2023-09: Eclipse 4.29.0


EDIT:
If the version control of your code is Git, as an alternative way, you can try to use Eclipse EGit.


Is there any other way to integrate Azure Devops with Eclipse for code sharing in that case

@NarmadhaPriya, You might try Eclipse EGit if you are using Git as the version control of your code.

We cannot use third party other than Azure devops

@NarmadhaPriya, EGit is provided by Eclipse Team.
